# DataListItem to DropDownList or TextBox VB.Net

Tags: ctypes, datalistitem

I have a DataListItem which can potentially be a dropdownlist or a textbox. To get the value I would need to do:

```
 CType(item.FindControl("myControl"), TextBox).Text
```

Or

```
CType(item.FindControl("myControl"), DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString()
```

The problem is, if it's a dropdownlist I get..

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'
>   to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Is there a way to check if the CType will take before Ctyping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TryCast:

```
Dim txt as TextBox = TryCast(item.FindControl("myControl"), TextBox)
If txt Is Nothing Then
    TryCast(item.FindControl("myControl"), DropDownList)
End If
```